# Eclipse Jave Swing Unidentified Error

Tags: java, swing, eclipse-indigo

When am trying to move a button or any components in my java swing application, a error message is popping up.

***Error message***
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your variable names.

If you are using variable name like net,com,org,java,edu,or javax change that to something else.

Comment: I din found any thing like that.